# Binary Tree Traversal (Mostly) Failing

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

For class, I have to create a binary tree of state objects, each of which includes a binary tree of resident objects organizing the people who live in each state. I'm trying to search the overall tree of states for a person by name (both state and resident trees are organized alphabetically by name), which involves traversing the entire tree of states and searching each state's resident tree for said person. Clearly my state tree traversal isn't working because most of the time, it tells me the person is not in the database (i.e. my stateforperson method, listed below, of the tree returns NULL) when I know for a fact that they do exist in the database. I am certain that my searchfor() method works.

```
node <Person*> * stateforperson (string nm, node <T> * n)
{    if (n !=  NULL)
     {
         node <Person*> * person = n->data->residents->searchfor(nm);
         if (person != NULL)
             return person;
         return stateforperson(nm, n->left);
         return stateforperson(nm, n->right);
     }
     else
         return NULL;
}
```

Attempted Update:

```
node <Person*> * stateforperson (string nm, node <T> * n)
{        if (n !=  NULL)
         {
             node <Person*> * person = n->data->residents->searchfor(nm);
             if (person != NULL)
                 return person;
             // Here, you explore the left branch and get the results.
             node <Person*> * left_ret = stateforperson(nm, n->left);
             // Here, same with right branch.
             node <Person*> * right_ret = stateforperson(nm, n->right);
             // You now have both results.
             if (left_ret != NULL) // If a result was found in left branches, you return that person. 
                 return left_ret;
             else if (right_ret != NULL) // Same with right branch.
                 return right_ret;
             else // The problem was here. Before you returned uninitialized memory. (because there wasn't a specified return value.
             // Now, you return a NULL pointer if nothing was found. 
             //So you detect that no person was found and don't use unitialized memeory.
                 return (NULL);
              }
              else
                  return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: So no state name is provided? You just have to search every state tree?

Comment: Yup. Professor knows I know how to search for a state; now he's testing to see if we can search trees within trees, and deal with traversals that don't necessarily require a specific order to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that what's happening is that you only explore the left nodes. Never go right because you return before :

```
     return stateforperson(nm, n->left); 
     // Here you just return the left part. Never reaching the following line
     return stateforperson(nm, n->right);
```

Try actually storing the values and something more like :

```
    left_ret = stateforperson(nm, n->left);
    right_ret = stateforperson(nm, n->right);
```

Than do whatever checks you need done on your variables to return the correct one.

(I believe that is the problem at least. Haven't done any recursive programming in a while so i could be mistaken.)

Comment: Doesn't look like a mistake, since traversing the call tree all the way down the left will eventually return a left person, or `NULL`

Comment: Yes, a left person. But he never actually checks any right part of the tree. So realistically, he's exploring 30% of his tree. So of course, does not find the person he needs. In some cases he will. If the person is in a left branch.

Comment: That's the thing -- I need it to break the traversal to return only if the person's name given was found inside the state presently being visited; otherwise, keep moving on. If both halves of the tree were searched and still the person was never found, only THEN do I want to return `NULL`. So I really don't know how to make it search both left and right and only return if the person is found in one of the states. Does that make sense? In other words, I don't even know what checks I would do on `left_ret` or `right_ret`. This recursion is making no sense to me.

Comment: Yup. But as i said, try storing your variables and not returning immediately. something like `return ((left_ret != 0 ? left_ret : right_ret));` If i understood correctly.

Comment: @Khaldor See above: I added the attempted update, which still only works some of the time, and leaves me with seg faults the other times (including cases in which I deliberately search for people I know are nowhere in the database.)

Comment: @sar add in an `else { return(0); }` You might be getting unitiailized pointers due to not returning a value. Thus leading to segmentation fault

Comment: WONDERFUL, IT WORKS! I still... I don't understand why it works. I have so many returns, how is it only getting to the proper one? @Khaldor would you be able to just briefly explain what exactly happens? It'd be much much appreciated.

Comment: @sar It's really a pity mp's don't exist or i didn't find them. But paste your final code at the bottom of your post and i'll try to walk through briefly.

Comment: @sar I added in an edit with comments and the final code that should wokr. Accept it if it helps understanding this better. :)

Comment: Yes thank you! It makes lots of sense! I accepted the answer. Unfortunately, I have a new question I'm about to ask, haha. Binary trees were kind of sped through in class so I don't wholly understand them, yet.

Comment: I'll be watching new questions.